# Scrapyard pay bug

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I own the Scrapyard in GTA V with Franklin. For the past 5 weeks, I have gotten $0. I've gone near there but no bikers are attacking. Is it a bug or what?

Comment: Have you been destroying cars as Franklin, Michael, or Trevor?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Car_Scrapyard), you can only collect income from destroyed cars.

> it will generate $150 per car that is destroyed by Franklin, Michael or Trevor, with a cap of $5,000 per week.

So this is easily testable, destroy some cars, wait for a week and you should receive the income.